# Suggest some alternatives to When... Then...?

Tags: synonyms

I have been summarising a novel and it seems that I am using the sentences of the form When .... Then .... A lot. It has become boring and repetitive.

Hence Please suggest some alternatives to sentences of the form When.... then....

Comment: I suppose it might do the trick

Comment: You can 'accept' the answer below if you like!

Answer (score -1):

1. Just leave out the word *then*:

   > When he asked a question, he got an immediate response. Not "When he asked a question, then he got an immediate response."
2. Reverse the order for a change:

   > Right before the story concludes, the author reveals the true motive. Or: Before he began to do this, he did that. On his way to this, he did that.
3. Show us what the connection of events is beyond just chronology:

   > The structure of 'When A then B' is the plainest of chronological order. Instead of "When he left work, then he walked home," try "Because he left work so early, he had the time to walk home."